# Virtual Host not pointing properly

Tags: apache, laravel-4, httpd.conf, vhosts

I have installed Laravel at C:/Apache24/htdocs/lsapp.

It's working fine with localhost/lsapp/public URL.

What I want to do is instead of above URL I want to access it by mak.org on my local machine.

For that I did following changes

1. Edited C:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf with below lines:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot "C:/Apache24/htdocs"
       ServerName localhost
   </VirtualHost>

   <VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot "C:/Apache24/htdocs/lsapp/public"
       ServerName mak.org
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
2. Edited C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts with below lines:

   ```
   127.0.0.1       localhost
   127.0.0.1       mak.org
   ```
3. I restarted my apache server.

But when I hit mak.org in browser, instead of accessing "C:/Apache24/htdocs/lsapp/public" it is pointing to "C:/Apache24/htdocs".

I restarted my PC, enabled opcache.enable=0 in php.ini still not getting desired outcome.

Can anybody help me on this?
What or where am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue resolved by enabling below in httpd.conf file of Apache:

```
    Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```